# Predictions and forecasting with mixed-effects models

Tags: regression, mixed-model, forecasting, references, random-effects-model

I am not sure I fully understand how mixed-effects models (such as [mixed-effects PK/PD models](http://smai.emath.fr/cemracs/cemracs09/talks/lectureLavielle.pdf)) can be used for forecasting.

**Some notations**

Let $p \in \mathbb{N}$ with $p \geq 2$. We assume that for each individual $i \in \lbrace 1,\ldots,p \rbrace$, we have $k_i \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ scalar observations $(y_{i,j})_{1 \leq j \leq k_i}$ obtained at times $(t_{i,j})_{1 \leq j \leq k_i}$. Therefore, for each individual, the observations are $\left( y_{i,j}, t_{i,j} \right)_{1 \leq j \leq k_i}$. We also assume the following model:

$$ y_{i,j} = f\left( t_{i,j}, b_i, \theta \right) + \varepsilon_{i,j} $$

where $\theta$ is a vector of parameters which contains *fixed effects* and *variance-covariance parameters* ; $b_i$ is a vector of *individual random effects* ; $f$ is sometimes called the *structural model* ; $\varepsilon_{i,j}$ is the observation noise. We assume that:

$$ b_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left( 0, \mathbf{D} \right), \quad \text{and} \quad \varepsilon_i = \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_{i,1} \\ \vdots \\ \varepsilon_{i, k_i} \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left( 0, \mathbf{\Sigma} \right). $$

The individual random effects $b_i$ are assumed i.i.d. and independent from $\varepsilon_i$.

**The question**

Given $\left( y_{i,j}, t_{i,j} \right)_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq p \\ 1 \leq j \leq k_i}}$, one can obtain an estimate $\hat{\theta}$ of the model parameters $\theta$ (which contain the unique coefficients in $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}$) by maximizing the model likelihood. This can be done, for instance, using stochastic versions of the EM algorithm (see link above).

Assume that $\hat{\theta}$ is available.

If we are given some observations $y_{s}^{\mathrm{new}}$ for a new individual $s \notin \lbrace 1, \ldots, p \rbrace$, its individual random effects are estimated by:

$$ \widehat{b_s} = \mathop{\mathrm{argmax}} \limits_{b_s} p\left( b_s \mid y_{s}^{\mathrm{new}}, \hat{\theta} \right) $$

where $p\left( \cdot \mid y_{s}^{\mathrm{new}}, \hat{\theta} \right)$ is the *posterior* distribution of the random effects given the new observations $y_{s}^{\mathrm{new}}$ and the point estimate of the model parameters $\hat{\theta}$. Thanks to Bayes' theorem, this is equivalent to maximizing the product "likelihood $\times$ prior:

$$ \widehat{b_s} = \mathop{\mathrm{argmax}} \limits_{b_s} p\left( y_{s}^{\mathrm{new}} \mid b_{s}, \hat{\theta} \right) p\left( b_{s} \mid \hat{\theta} \right). $$

Now, if $t \, \longmapsto \, f(t, \cdot, \cdot)$ is a continuous function of time, we may call it a *growth curve*. It describes the evolution of the measurements with time. Let $i_{0} \in \lbrace 1, \ldots, p \rbrace$ and $t$ such that $t_{i_{0},1} < \ldots < t_{i_{0},k_i} < t$.

> How can we use this mixed-effects model to predict the most likely value $y_{i_{0}}^{\ast}$ for individual $i_{0}$ at time $t$? This relates to forecasting since we want to predict the measurement value at a future time.

Naively, I would do as follows. Given $\left( y_{i,j}, t_{i,j} \right)_{\substack{1 \leq i \leq p \\ 1 \leq j \leq k_i}}$, I would estimate $\hat{\theta}$ (we estimate the model parameters using all the data including the past observations for individual $i_{0}$). Then I would estimate $\widehat{b_{i_{0}}}$ as described above. Eventually, I would say that:

$$ y_{i_{0}}^{\ast} = f\left( t, \widehat{b_{i_{0}}}, \hat{\theta} \right). $$

If this is right, I don't see how I would prove it mathematically. Still, I'm feeling like I'm missing something because this predicted value $y_{i_{0}}^{\ast}$ does not take into account the noise distribution. Also, I do not see how I would be able to estimate CIs for $y_{i_{0}}^{\ast}$ with this.

In a Bayesian setting (with a prior distribution on $\theta$), would I need to use the posterior predictive distribution (see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285690/how-to-make-predictions-with-the-posterior-predictive-distribution) and [these notes](http://people.stat.sc.edu/Hitchcock/stat535slidesday18.pdf))? From what I understand, if $y_{i_{0}}$ denotes the vector of the past observations for individual $i_{0}$, this posterior predictive distribution is given by:

$$ p\left( y_{i_{0}}^{\ast} \mid y_{i_{0}} \right) = \int_{\Theta} p\left( y_{i_{0}}^{\ast} \mid \theta, y_{i_{0}} \right) p\left( \theta \mid y_{i_{0}} \right) \, d\theta. $$

However, I'm not sure it applies here and I'm not sure where the random effects come in.

Any reference, explanation, hint,... is welcome ! :-)

Comment: +1! I was asking myself more or less the same question some time ago but I was unable to find relevant material (lecture notes, research papers) which deal with this topic (mixed-effects models + forecasting).

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, the procedure you describe is what it is typically done in mixed-effects models. When you fit the models under maximum-likelihood you only get $\hat \theta$, and then using empirical Bayes you get an estimate of $\hat b_i(\hat \theta)$, which you plug-in the equation to obtain a prediction for a particular subject. In the context of linear mixed models, the resulting predictions are calls Best Linear Unbiased Predictions (BLUPs), and you can find more info, for example in, Searle, Casella and McCulloch (1992, Chapter 7) or in McLean, Sanders and Stroup (1991, *The American Statistician* **45**, 54-64).

Calculating standard errors or a confidence interval is more tricky but could be done with a procedure that mimics the Bayesian approach. That is, you could repeat the following steps, say $M = 1000$ times:

1. Simulate $\theta^*$ from $\mathcal N\{\hat \theta, \mbox{var}(\hat\theta)\}$.
2. Simulate $b_i^*$ from the posterior distribution of the random effects, i.e., $[p(y_i \mid b; \theta^*) p(b; \theta^*)]$.
3. Calculate $y_{pred}^*(m) = f(t, \theta^*, b_i^*)$

The first step accounts for the uncertainty in the maximum likelihood estimates, and the second step accounts for the uncertainty in the random effects.

You can get as an estimate for standard error using the sample standard deviation of the $y_{pred}^*(1), \ldots, y_{pred}^*(M)$ values.